# Does Ubuntu work with 4K Laptops?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, display-resolution, zooming, 4k-monitor

I am about to buy a 4K laptop and I would like to run Ubuntu 15.10 on it. I believe that shouldn't be a big problem. I'm sure I can adjust the text and the Unity UI just right.

The thing is that I use VirtualBox quite often for running Ubuntu Server on it. I believe to run into problems here. When not yet set, the text within the guest operating system should be small and barely readable, right? Is there any way to do some scaling of the guest os view? Like for instance scale it by the factor of times 2? Is it possible to run applications that do not adapt to 4k with a kind of magnifying lens? Like for instance running VirtualBox with some double-size zoom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Ubuntu 4K-ready?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788099/is-ubuntu-4k-ready) **or** [hdpi - How do I increase the font size in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for a 4k laptop display? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035520/how-do-i-increase-the-font-size-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-for-a-4k-laptop-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this, but I just talked to a guy at System76 about why the Oryx Pro (which is a rebranded Clevo 650RE) doesn't have the 4k screen option that's offered on that frame.  He said that while Ubuntu 'works' it was not a 'nice out-of-box experience', so I'm guessing it doesn't look great.