# Kubuntu and Fonts

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, kubuntu, fonts, cuda

I just installed Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Now, after a dist-upgrade and cuda installation, I restarted, and after the login, all fonts were incredibly small. Font sizes were the same, so it's like somewhat a dpi scaling was forced systemwide (but dpi scaling is disabled)
Maybe the nvidia driver? 
I just installed nvidia stuff, anaconda, and some ML packages (keras, theano, etc..). No other software installed.

I can enlarge all fonts obviously, but some applications don't comply, and are quite unusable (e.g. nvidia nsight).

Is there some workaround?

Comment: did you check the screen resolution?

Comment: Seems like [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808270/font-size-is-too-small-in-kubuntu-16-04-with-a-4k-display-how-to-enlarge-the-si)

Comment: Screen resolution is native, 1080p.

I'll check the issue cited by Redbob. Thanks, mates.

Comment: Guys, I was unsatisfied of Kubuntu poor stability, so I fresh-installed mint-KDE.

Same issue. The fonts were ok, I upgraded my distro via the update manager, and upon reboot my fonts were super tiny.
The font sizes did NOT change. DPI scaling was and is disabled.