# Can't use any programs in full-screen mode on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: fullscreen, flicker

When I try to use full screen mode on any program, be it sites under Firefox, games with Lutris/wine or VLC, the screen starts to flicker and switches between full-screen mode and a smaller resolution of the screen in the top left corner of my monitor.

Would be grateful for any ideas that could help me tackle this major problem.

I am using a 4K monitor and have fractional scaling enabled as an experimental feature. This seems to cause the problem, but I can't go without it since at 100% scaling everything is just too tiny to read and 200% doesn't look very good, so I keep everything at 150%.

Also this problem only started recently after I updated one of my Lutris games. I didn't have this problem before.

Comment: Hardware requirements, e.g. 4k graphic card and software Ubuntu OS and software capabilities. When both are ready, you can set System Setting > display setting to 4k resolution, imo. https://askubuntu.com/questions/788099/is-ubuntu-4k-ready

Comment: You probably identified the culprit: an experimental feature. Can you not work around choosing a fixed scaling, but then changing the font scaling factor in Gnome Tweaks (Fonts tab)? This combination offers quite some flexibility to make it work acceptably.

Comment: @vanadium while that works in some areas, Icons and UI scaled at 200% just take up way too much screen space, and the Font scaling doesn't scale most apps, so it only really works with Gnome Apps. Take [this example](https://imgur.com/a/Yv5Lbso). The System fonts are a good size for my monitor, but everything else is just way too big.

This is 200% Display scaling and 75% font scaling.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same distribution (19.10) with 4k display scaled by factor 2 and i didn't face such issue for **all** applications, **but** any browser which is based on Chromium (Chrome, Opera, Chromium itself etc.) behaves exactly as you describe, even on Youtube with full-screen mode.

As a workaround i'm running `google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=1` with default page zoom at 200% for all websites (Chrome -> Settings -> Page Zoom).

**P.S.**
Advise you to check Gnome Extensions if you have, since i faced somehow similar weird bugs with applications scale in case of hidden Gnome top bar or left sidebar.

Comment: Disabling the Gnome Top Bar hiding did it for me, never thought that would be the cause. Thanks!